# Java for Clojure users

Tags: java, api, clojure

I've been using Lisp on and off, and I'm catching up with clojure. 
The good thing about clojure is that I can use all the java functions naturally, and the bad thing about clojure is also that I have to know java function naturally.

For example, I had to spend some time (googling) to find square function in Java (Math/sqrt in clojure notation).

Could you recommend me some good information resource for Java functions (libraries) for clojure users that are not so familiar with Java?

It can be anything - good books, webpages, forums or whatever.

Comment: At first I thought you wanted to switch from clojure to java! Almost had a heart attack.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had similar problems when I first started using Clojure. I had done some Java development years ago, but was still pretty unfamiliar with the libraries out there.

## Intro

I find the easiest way to use Java is to not *really* use it. I think a book would be a little bit much to just get started using Java from Clojure. There isn't that much you really need to know, unless you really start getting down into the JVM/Java libraries. Let me explain.

Spend more time learning how to use Clojure inside and out, and become familiar with Clojure-Contrib. For instance, `sqrt` [is in generic.math-functions](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/generic.math-functions-api.html#clojure.contrib.generic.math-functions/sqrt) in clojure.contrib.

Many of the things you'll need are in fact already in Clojure–but still plenty are not.

Become familiar with calling conventions and syntactic sugar in Clojure for using Java. e.g. `Math/sqrt`, as per your example, is calling the static method (which just a function, basically) `sqrt` from the class `Math`.

Anyway, here's a guide that should help you get started if you find yourself *really* needing to use Java. I'm going to assume you've done *some* imperative OO programming, but not much else. And even if you haven't, you should be okay.

---

## Isaac's Clojurist's Guide to Java

### Classes

A class is a bundle of methods (functions which act on the class) that
can also be a data type: e.g. to create a new class of the type `Double` : `(Double. 1.2)` which initializes the class Double (the period is the syntactic sugar for calling the class constructor methods, which initialize the class with the values you provide) with the value `1.2`.

Now, look at the [`Double` class](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) in the Java 6 API:

```
Double

public Double(double value)

Constructs a newly allocated Double object that represents the 
primitive double argument.

Parameters:
value - the value to be represented by the Double.
```

So you can see what happened there. You "built" a new `Double` with value `1.2`, which is a double. A little confusing there, but really a Double is a class that represents a Double and can do things relating to doubles.

### Static Methods

For instance, to parse a Double value out of a string, we can use the static method (meaning we don't need a particular instance of `Double`, we can just call it like we called `sqrt`) `parseDouble(String s)`:

```
(Double/parseDouble "1.2") => 1.2
```

Not to tricky there.

### Nonstatic Methods

Say we want to use a Java class that we initialized to something. Not too difficult:

```
(-> (String. "Hey there") ;; make a new String object
    (.toUpperCase)) ;; pass it to .toUpperCase (look up -> to see what it does)
                    ;; toUpperCase is a non-static method

=> "HEY THERE"
```

So now we've used a method which is not static, and which requires a real, live `String` object to deal with. Let's look at how the docs say it works:

```
toUpperCase

public String toUpperCase()

Converts all of the characters in this String to upper case using 
the rules of the default locale. This method is equivalent to
toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()).

Returns:
the String, converted to uppercase.
```

So here we have a method which returns a string (as shown by the "String" after the public in the definition, and takes no parameters. But wait! It does take a parameter. In Python, it'd be the implicit parameter `self`: this is called `this` in Java.

We could also use the method like this: `(.toUpper (String. "Hey there"))` and get the same result.

### More on Methods

Since you deal with mutable data and classes in Java, you need to be able to apply functions to Classes (instances of Classes, really) and not expect a return value.

For instance, say we're dealing with a `JFrame` from the `javax.swing` library. We might need to do a number of things *to* it, not *with it* (you generally operate *with* values, not *on* them in functional languages). We can, like this:

```
(doto (JFrame. "My Frame!");; clever name
   (.setContentPane ... here we'd add a JPanel or something to the JFrame)
   (.pack) ;; this simply arranges the stuff in the frame–don't worry about it
   (.setVisibleTrue)) ;; this makes the Frame visible
```

`doto` just passes its first argument to all the other functions you supply it, and passes it as the first argument to them. So here we're just doing a lot of things *to* the `JFrame` that don't return anything in particular. All these methods are listed as methods of the `JFrame` in the documentation (or its superclasses… don't worry about those yet).

### Wrapping up

This should prepare you for now exploring [the JavaDocs](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) yourself. Here you'll find everything that is available to you in a standard Java 1.6 install. There will be new concepts, but a quick Google search should answer most of your questions, and you can always come back here with specific ones.

Be sure to look into the other important Clojure functions like `proxy` and `reify` as well as `extend-type` and its friends. I don't often use them, but when I need to, they can be invaluable. I still am understanding them myself, in fact.

There's a ton out there, but it's mostly a problem of volume rather than complexity. It's not a bad problem to have.

#### Additional reading:

- [Static or Nonstatic?](http://cscie160-distance.com/nonstatic.html) ;; a guide to statis vs. nonstatic methods
- [The Java Class Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library) ;; an overview of what's out there, with a nice picture
- [The JavaDocs](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) ;; linked above
- [Clojure Java Interop Docs](http://clojure.org/java_interop) ;; from the Clojure website
- [Best Java Books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far) ;; as per clartaq's answer

Comment: +1 for an awesome answer. I'm now wondering if it would be possible to create a (java-explain someclass) function in Clojure that would intelligently tell you how to call all the methods from Clojure via reflection + JavaDoc lookup? No need to learn any Java at all then!

Comment: A little note: Strings in Clojure are already Java strings. So `(String. "Hey there")` is the same as just `"Hey there"`

Comment: Clojure contrib is now depreciated. Please update the link.

Answer (score 2):

My first question would be: what do you exactly need? There are many Java libraries out there. Or do you just need the standard libraries? In that case the answer given by [dbyrne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181412/dbyrne) should be enough.

Keep in mind that in general you are better of using the Clojure data structures like sequences instead of the Java equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

Really, any good Java book can get you started. See for example the answer to the question about the
[best Java book people have read so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far#76344). There are lots of good sources there.

Once you have a little Java under you belt, using it is all just a matter of simple Clojure syntax.

Mastering the content of the voluminous Java libraries is a much bigger task than figuring out how to use them in Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the Sun (now Oracle) Java Tutorials: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Then dive into the Java 6 API docs:
http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/

Then ask questions on #clojure IRC or the mailing list, and read blogs.

For a deep dive into Java the language, I recommend Bruce Eckel's free *Thinking in Java*:
http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/

Answer (score 0):

I think the plain old [Java 6
API Specification](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)  should be pretty much all you need.

Comment: I don't agree with this at all. Throwing someone new to Java into the API will just drown them. And the API docs are sometimes misleading. Look at how the java.awt package is stated to "Contains all of the classes for creating user interfaces ..." never even mentioning Swing, for example. Although the API spec is the ultimate _reference_, it's not a good place for a newbie to start IMO.

Comment: @clartaq: I would agree with your point if he was actually learning to program java.  As a clojure programmer all you really need is a java reference.  Any specific topics like UI or IO programming can be googled on an as-needed basis.  You really don't need to go through any java tutorials to get started with clojure.  OTOH, I learned Clojure after using Java for a decade, so maybe I am coming from a bad perspective.